# How do I use a Consumer with a PopupMenu?

Tags: flutter, dart

This gives me access to some functions in my Bloc:

```
Consumer<ProviderMaps>(builder: (context, Provmap, widget) {
```

I can later call functions like so if the Consumer is above:

```
Provmap.addMarker(_lastMapPosition);
```

How can I enable Provmap inside of a void like this?:

```
  void onClickMenu(MenuItemProvider item) {
    if( item.menuTitle.startsWith('P')) {
      _addMarkerTarget2(_lastMapPosition);
    }
    if( item.menuTitle.startsWith('S')) {
      Provmap.addMarker(_lastMapPosition);
    }
  }
```

"Undefined name 'Provmap'"

Answer (score 0):

got it...

```
Provider.of<ProviderMaps>(context, listen: false)
      .addMarker(_lastMapPosition);
```